# how to group traits together, encapsulating them as a group

Tags: python-2.7, enthought, traits, mayavi

I have a coordinate system that it makes sense to treat as a "whole group". They initialize, change, and reset simultaneously. I also like to not re-render as many times as I  have coordinates when one changes. Here is the simplified version of what I have in mind, but I can't quite get there. Thanks.

Cleaner code is better in my case even if it uses more advanced features. Could the class 'Coord' be wrapped as a trait itself?

```
from traits.api import *

class Coord(HasTraits):
    x=Float(1.0)
    y=Float(1.0)
    def __init__(self,**traits):
        HasTraits.__init__(self,**traits)

class Model:
    coord=Instance(Coord)
    @on_trait_change('coord')##I would so have liked this to "just work"
    def render(self):#reupdate render whenever coordinates change

class Visualization:
    model=Instance(Model)

    def increment_x(self):
        self.model.coord.x+=1 ##should play well with Model.render
    def new_coord(self):
        self.model.coord=Coord(x=2,y=2) ##should play well with Model.render
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your source code.  `Model` and `Visualization` both need to be `HasTraits` classes for the listener to work.

Also, it is rare to actually need to write the `__init__` method of a `HasTraits` class.  Traits is designed to work without it.  That said, if you *do* write an `__init__` method, make sure to use `super` to properly traverse the method resolution order.  (Note that you will find this inconsistently implemented in the extant documentation and examples.)

Finally, use the `'anytrait'` name to listen for any trait:

```
from traits.api import Float, HasTraits, Instance, on_trait_change

class Coord(HasTraits):
    x=Float(1.0)
    y=Float(1.0)

class Model(HasTraits):
    coord=Instance(Coord, ())
    @on_trait_change('coord.anytrait')  # listens for any trait on `coord`.
    def render(self):
        print "I updated"

class Visualization(HasTraits):
    model=Instance(Model, ())

    def increment_x(self):
        self.model.coord.x+=1  # plays well with Model.render
    def new_coord(self):
        self.model.coord=Coord(x=2,y=2)  # plays well with Model.render
```

Here's my output:

```
>>> v = Visualization()
>>> v.increment_x()
I updated
>>> v.new_coord()
I updated
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. To answer the question more fully though, you should demonstrate "v.new_coord()". The point is that v.new_coord should only trigger model.render() once. My (I think ugly) workaround at the moment is to set each coordinate individually and then another variable flush_coordinate_changes, which I set to True. I only listen for flush_coordinate_changes.

Comment: Second point. I see the HasTraits __init__ method called all the time by subclasses in documentation. [Here](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_mayavi_traits_ui.html?highlight=hastraits) is the first example I found. Admittedly from mayavi code, not strictly traits.

Comment: Can't edit previous post. Guess it has been too long. (Google search)["https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=%22Do%20not%20forget%20to%20call%20the%20parent%27s%20__init__%22&oq=%22Do%20not%20forget%20to%20call%20the%20parent%27s%20__init__%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.1687j0j1"]: 
"Do not forget to call the parent's __init__" with quotes, with init

Comment: Traits is designed to work without an explicit `__init__` method, although it is *sometimes* necessary, especially when you need have both dynamic default methods and static listeners.  Usually, however, it is not required.

Comment: @user3391229 I have updated the code output and my explanation somewhat to clarify.  My comment about `__init__` was a little off at first.